# How do I save this text file into a list in python

Tags: python, list, io, split

I have a text file that consists of 1 column of numbers (like: 1e-5, 1.15e3, etc). 
How do I save the column to a list as just floats?

input text file looks like this:

```
 1.00E-05
 1.06E-05
 1.13E-05
 1.19E-05
```

I tried this:

```
file=open('C:\Users\Enrique Jr\Desktop\h_energy.txt', "r")
h_energy=[]
for line in file:
h_energy.append((line.split()))
file.close()
```

and got an output of this:

```
[['1.00E-05'], ['1.06E-05'], ['1.13E-05'], ['1.19E-05']
```

Comment: According to your example output, your text file has only one column of numbers, and they are all integers. There are no tab separators. But it does not matter, you've got plenty of useful answers already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
file=open('output.txt', "r")
array = []
for line in file:
    array.append(float(line.rstrip()))
file.close()
```

Comment: This works well but I need the values in the "array" to be floats

Comment: Please select it as the answer by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer if this solved your problem...

Comment: Will do. Sorry new to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the csv reader library in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

It will be something like this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('output.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
...     data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
...     print data
[["1", "2"], ["3.4", "5"], ...]
```

You will need to convert the data from text to float or int yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=open('output.txt', "r")
for line in file:
    list.append(float(line.split("\t")[0]))
    list.append(float(line.split("\t")[1]))
file.close()
```

If you require ints and floats to be stored as different types and not just have 
float representation of integers, then you would need to try-catch to see if you can
parse as an int, and if not then as a float:

```
try:
    list.append(int(line.split("\t")[0]))
except ValueError:
    try:
        inNumberfloat = float(inNumber)
        list.append(float(line.split("\t")[0]))
    except ValueError:
        #neither an int nor float
```